# What would be the word for a thing which happens to be the third generation of something?

Tags: word-request

Like in this sentence: “Canon 70D is the _____(the word here) of Canon 90D.”

Note that, there was a model called 80D before 90D. 70D is the grandfather of the 90D.

What would be the word here?

Comment: **(A) predecessor** comes to mind but you'll find other possibilities at:   https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/precede.html

Comment: a later generation of x; newer model

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of an analogy to human generations, you can say "grandparent" or "grandmother". This is fairly common and would likely be understood without explanation.

Perhaps I should note that in the past it was fairly common to use feminine terms when referring to mechanical objects, like "grandmother" here. But today this is considered sexist or something so we usually use generic words like "grandparent".

It's also more common to express the relationship the other way around. That is, to say, "The 90D is the grandchild of the 70D" rather than "the 70D is the grandparent of the 90D."

Using "grandchild" would likely be seen as a metaphor. If you want to be more literal, you could say "second generation predecssor of".

Comment: You can also say ""The 70D is **the forerunner** of the 90D". **The** implies there was no 60D, or, if there was, then the 60D was completely different. If there was a 60D and it was similar, then **a forerunner**

Comment: @Greybeard Sure. A word like "forerunner" or "predecessor" works as long as it's not important to specify how many generations elapsed.

Comment: I agree. In the context of a 70D, an 80D, and a 90D, the generations are pretty self-explanatory. I'd be quite happy with "grandfather" - I don't think equal opportunity stretches to figurative use of inanimate objects.

Answer (score -1):

*Ancestor* is the word I would use there.

Answer (score -2):

Canon 70D is the third precursor, third predecessor

Canon 90D is the tertiated generation

Comment: The 70D would be the *second* precursor, or the *second* predecessor. The citations of "second precursor" I found were only in chess and chemistry. The citations of "second predecessor" were legal and software terminology. Please give citations where these terms might have a parallel usage to iterations in a line of cameras. Also, none of Merriam-Webster, Oxford, Collins or Cambridge recognize "*tertiate*" as a word. Please cite reliable sources for that.